# Building an API for long distance customers with IOS App, single or multiple calls?

Tags: api, server, laravel

I am in the process of building an API in Laravel and my server is currently stored in the UK. Now I have read some of the posts relating to this topic on Stack but I am still a little unsure as to the best approach.

I am wondering whether to make single or multiple calls to the API when loading screen data for the app. I like the idea of multiple smaller calls as I tend to build with MVC in mind and modules but it turns out most customers are in South America. I was more worried about latency as the size of the calls won't be an issue.

What is your opinion on this issue? I was thinking of creating a single end point for each screen on the API and then using the modules to pull together the relevant data and send it back in one return.

Comment: Are the calls dependent on each other? If not, they may be made concurrently, so your users don't incur double latency. Maybe setting up a test environment with simulated latency might be helpful to decide how each solution performs.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Your comment is the answer - there is no "one size fits all" solution; the OP is going to have to simulate & test.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I think I will do some testing to find out.